# Hibernate many to many mapping additional column Timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, timestamp, many-to-many

I am a newbie to Hibernate and trying to do something like this:

I have 2 tables. 
One is **`Visitor`** and another is **`Visited_Page`**.

The **`Visitor`** table has a structure:

```
{
visitor_id *int*,
visitor_username *varchar*,
visito_name *varchar*
}
```

The **Visited_Page** table structure is:

```
{
vipage_id *int*,
vipage_url *varchar*
}
```

And many to many mapped table structure is like:

> visitor_id *int*, vipage_id *int*.

When the User hits a `URL` in my website, a new entry should get created in the mapped table with the structure as mentioned above.
I have completed this part using hibernate with annotations in Java.

Now I have to add another column **`Timestamp`** in the mapped table. I am not able to find how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class say `VistorVisitedPage`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Vistor_Visited_Page")
@AssociationOverrides({

public class VistorVisitedPage {

    private Date createdDate;
    private String createdBy;

}
```

Also refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) for complete information.